# How do I get the width and height of a doc generated with FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

How can I get height and width of a document in FPDF.

For example, I've next line:

```
$this->Cell(200,5,'ATHLETIC DE COLOMBIA S.A.',1,1,'C',1);
```

But, I want to do something like:

```
// $x = width of page
$this->Cell($x,5,'ATHLETIC DE COLOMBIA S.A.',1,1,'C',1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**note: read Ross' McLellan's answer below**

As far as I remember you can't do it with vanilla FPDF. You can either extend it to have a method that would return this value for you, or just store the width as a public property of fpdf object.

Comment: width: $this->w
height: $this->h

Answer (score 49):

Needed to do this myself so was just checking the most recent version of FPDF and it looks like the width & height are already available as public properties. So for anyone looking for the same info:

```
$pdf = new FPDF(); 
$pdf->addPage("P", "A4");

$pdf -> w; // Width of Current Page
$pdf -> h; // Height of Current Page

$pdf -> Line(0, 0, $pdf -> w, $pdf -> h);
$pdf -> Line($pdf -> w, 0, 0, $pdf -> h);

$pdf->Output('mypdf.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, although this isn't on the documentation page.

Comment: You have to change publicity to public in current FPDF version.

Comment: GetPageWidth() is available now

Comment: @hendr1x GetPageWidth() isnt working in v16

Answer (score 15):

## **Update: November 2017**

Nowadasy, you can simply call `GetPageWidth` and `GetPageHeight` methods.

```
$pdf = new FPDF(); 
$pdf->addPage("P", "A4");

$pdf->GetPageWidth();  // Width of Current Page
$pdf->GetPageHeight(); // Height of Current Page
```

Comment: What measurement is returned from `GetPageWidth`? pixels? mm? cm?

Comment: mm, cm, pt or inches. By default it's mm. You can change it specifying another measurement at the creation of `FPDF`.

Answer (score 8):

Encase someone needs to get the width taking margins into consideration...

```
class FPDF_EXTEND extends FPDF
{

    public function pageWidth()
    {
        $width = $this->w;
        $leftMargin = $this->lMargin;
        $rightMargin = $this->rMargin;
        return $width-$rightMargin-$leftMargin;
    }

}
```